# KeyError: access token

Tags: django

I have already test this before and it's work. Now the error back again and I didn't do any changes on my social app.

Here are my codes:

```
def get_profile(request, token=None):
    args = {
        'client_id': settings.FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
        'client_secret': settings.FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
        'redirect_uri': request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('social:fb_callback')),
        'code': token,
    }

    target = urllib.urlopen('https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?' + urllib.urlencode(args)).read()
    response = cgi.parse_qs(target)
    access_token = response['access_token'][-1]

    return access_token
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, your request is not successful and the response doesn't have an access token. According to facebook docs, when a request isn't good, it returns a response with an error element, something like:

```
{
  error: {
    message: "Missing redirect_uri parameter.",
    type: "OAuthException",
    code: 191
  }
}
```

So, in your function, you should do something like:

```
class FacebookAccessException(Exception): pass

def get_profile(request, token=None):
    ...
    response = json.loads(urllib_response)
    if 'error' in response:
        raise FacebookAccessException(response['error']['message'])

    access_token = response['access_token'][-1]
    return access_token
```

**PS:**

Try to use better urllib. You should try [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/).

Comment: is it possible that facebook will not give an access token?

Comment: It is, indeed, you should check Facebook Docs.